# How to reduce VM size?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have a Virtualbox VM, with a .vdi that is taking 49gb in the host machine.

I may have used that much space inside the VM once, but now I'm only really using about 6gb.

I tried this command for virtualbox:

```
vboxmanage modifyhd /path/to/disk.vdi --compact
```

It started working 0%..10%.....100%. But nothing really happened, the .vdi was still 49gb.

Then I run 'df -h' in the VM and found this:

```
root@mypc# df -h
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/mypc-root       2.0T   38G  1.9T   2% /
udev                        1.3G  4.0K  1.3G   1% /dev
tmpfs                       502M  784K  501M   1% /run
none                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                        1.3G  160K  1.3G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda1                   228M   31M  185M  15% /boot
/home/someuser/.Private     2.0T   38G  1.9T   2% /home/someuser
```

I don't know why it is using 38gb there.

I cleaned the Trash but it didn't help.

Any ideas on what else I can do?

The VM has Ubuntu 12, with encrypted LVM and home (that's the .Private dir).
The host has Windows 7.

**UPDATE**

I was able to free space for /dev/sda1, but not for /dev/mapper/mypc-root. Zerofree starts and never ends, though I can tell the disk has stopped writting because it stops doing noise after a minute.

Here's the output for 'df -ih'

```
root@mypc:/home/someuser# df -ih
Filesystem                 Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/mypc-root        128M  208K  128M    1% /
udev                         311K   495  310K    1% /dev
tmpfs                        314K   428  314K    1% /run
none                         314K     4  314K    1% /run/lock
none                         314K     7  314K    1% /run/shm
/dev/sda1                    122K   230  122K    1% /boot
/home/someuser/.Private      128M  208K  128M    1% /home/someuser
```

Comment: Just curious: What is the output of `df -ih` ?

Comment: @StevenMonday There, I updated my post. And learned something new =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi):

> For this operation to be effective, it is required that free space in the guest system first be zeroed out using a suitable software tool. For Windows guests, you can use the `sdelete` tool provided by Microsoft. Execute `sdelete -c` in the guest to zero the free disk space before compressing the virtual disk image. For Linux, use the `zerofree` utility which supports ext2/ext3 filesystems.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the right answer. I created a sub-question here: http://superuser.com/questions/429199/how-to-umount-its-busy

Comment: Link to `sdelete`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443 (download: [zip file](http://download.sysinternals.com/files/SDelete.zip)).

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the [original answer that had this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11248/75035):

*In the VM:*

1. `dd if=/dev/zero of=test.file`
2. `sync`
3. `rm test.file`

*On the host machine:*

4. `VBoxManage modifyhd --compact your_image_path.vdi`

This is the only solution that I have tried that works. The `zerofree` and `sfill` (from `secure-delete`) don't work on my Debian VM (Windows 10 host).

Answer (score 0):

I think the core of your problem is that your root filesystem (`/`) is 2TB in size. With a filesystem that large, the relatively small overhead (inodes and such) is still quite large (>32GB, in your case).

If you want to shrink your virtual disk, you'll need to shrink your root filesystem first.