# How to free space on VirtualBox Debian VM

Tags: virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine

I have a Debian Jessie VM in VirtualBox that I use for C++ programming. The primary virtual disk is set to be dynamically allocated 32GB. Over time, I have gradually used more space on the virtual disk, but recently I cleared my Bazel cache and removed other extraneous files.

Running `df -h` on the VM yields:

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/sda1 31G 14G 15G 48% / 
udev 10M 0 10M 0% /dev 
tmpfs 403M 5.9M 397M 2% /run 
tmpfs 1006M 68K 1006M 1% /dev/shm 
tmpfs 5.0M 4.0K 5.0M 1% /run/lock 
tmpfs 1006M 0 1006M 0% /sys/fs/cgroup 
tmpfs 202M 4.0K 202M 1% /run/user/117 
tmpfs 202M 8.0K 202M 1% /run/user/1000
```

From the command output, it appears as if I have only 14GB of space used on the virtual disk, but the VDI file still has a size of 24.2GB. Is there any way to shrink the VDI to the current size of the virtual disk?

**EDIT:**
I have looked at the tools that were recommended by the other questions. None of them work for me, as I cannot figure out how to make `zerofree` run on my system and `sfill -fvz` (from `secure-delete`) only makes VirtualBox think the VM uses all of the 32 GB virtual disk. I don't know where to go from here.

Thanks,
Neil

Comment: It is brute force, but cloning the VM to another VDI will usually do the trick.  But treat it in procedure and complication like you are replacing a physical hard disk just virtually.  You will need to pre format and partition,  change UUIDs and configuration files and such, and for simplicity, you could even use disk cloning software.

Comment: "how to make `zerofree` run" -- You cannot install it or what? How about this solution with `dd`: [*How to make ext4 filesystem sparse?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11248/108618) (don't forget to `sync`, see comments there). "I don't know where to go from here." -- basic question, but your statement begs for it: did you try `vboxmanage modifyhd ... --compact`? If this `dd` solution works for you, then please make it a nice answer to [this other question](https://superuser.com/q/429170/432690). After that you can leave me a comment here below and I will upvote your answer there.

Comment: +KamilMaciorowski I was able to install it, but I couldn't run `zerofree`. That is the correct command, right? The `sync` command might've been my issue, I didn't know to run that. Does that command finalize the zeroed bits?

Comment: After what I had done, I did run `vboxmanage modifyhd ... --compact`. That recovered the space up until what it was before I started: ~24GB.

Comment: +KamilMaciorowski Yes, the `dd` method works quite well indeed. It recovered all of the storage space. I posted an answer to the question you said. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Answer upvoted. Side note: I didn't get notifications you addressed me in your comments; I'm here only because I tend to monitor my recent comments. The right syntax is like @ifconfig , the plus sign doesn't work.